# Why is position: fixed not working?

Tags: html, css

Why is `position: fixed;` not working in the following css

```
body {
    text-align : center ;
    min-width : 770px ;
}
div.wrapper {
    width : 770px ;
    text-align : left ;
    margin-left : auto ;
    margin-right : auto ;
}

div.header {
    color: blue;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
}

div#main {
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    padding: 10px;
}

div.footer {
    color: blue;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="GET">
            Start Datum: <input type="text" name="start" pattern="[0-9]{4}"/>
            Eind Datum: <input type="text" name="eind" pattern="[0-9]{4}"/>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>


   <div class="main">
       <div id="donutchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
       <?php
           $i=0;
           foreach ($rows as $row) {
               echo '<div id="chart'.$i.'_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>';
               $i++;
           }
       ?>
   </div>
   <hr>
   <div class="footer">
       ©2014-<?php echo date("Y"); ?> guest
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Share your HTML please.

Comment: What do you mean by NOT WORKING?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? Why are you providing a lot of CSS that appears unrelated to the fixed header but no HTML that is?

Comment: situations in which it does not work? can specifically say? html markup and show

Comment: It's fixed for me??? I had to give your wrapper a `height` of `1000px` to allow scrolling. http://jsfiddle.net/Jrn8E/

Comment: @Scott i did copy your css exactly but when i try it in a browser the header just dissappears.

Comment: Which browser are you using? try it on another browser.. you might have some browser compatibility issues

Comment: I tried it on chrome and firefox.

Comment: @Scott it has something to do with `<div class="main">` I think it's overlapping the header.

Comment: @user3531238 looks like you can't even distinguish between actual header and the **horizontal rule** (rendered by the `hr` tag) which is placed on top of the header. That rule is the only one scrolled upwards, the header itself is fixed expectedly.

Comment: @user3531238 What do you expect it to do? It is working fine.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me? on the fiddle and when I save it to my machine. just to be clear, you want your header to stay at the top of page when the user scrolls down the page?

Comment: I think the content in `<div class="main">..</div>` is overlapping the header.

Comment: So something like this? [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/tV3AA/1/)

Comment: @Ruddy How do i make it so that the content of `<div class="main">` should go to background and the header should come to foreground.

Comment: @user3531238 Its in my demo. `z-index` will do that. So I put your header to `10` it will be infront unless you have anything else with `z-index` set higher.

Comment: @user3531238 Glad I could help, if you dont mind I will put that as the answer so you can accept it. Could be useful to other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so took a little while to understand what you meant by "not working" but we got there in the end.

### Changed CSS:

```
div.header {
    color: blue;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

So the main thing you needed by the sound of it was `z-index`, this can move the header to the front (setting a value `z-index: 10;`). Also I added width and a border to make it look nicer.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/tV3AA/1/)